# Grum timeout = 0, lost admin password, wanting fresh Ubuntu 20 install

Tags: grub2, upgrade, password, timeout

Help! I want to update my Ubuntu 18.04 to the latest version. I forgot my admin password so can't update from the loaded current install. I also am unable to get into the grub menu because I changed its timeout to 0 way back when. I can't change the grub file without my admin password which, again, buhbye from above.

It's an old machine (Samsung 5, from like 2012ish), and a complete wipe is actually what I want.

Any tips for this catch 22?

Comment: Boot from a LiveUSB and fix the grub timeout.

Comment: I can't because there's no second I can seem to catch the BIOS screen. I've tried pressing ESC, SHIFT, all the Fs in the moments from boot until the Ubuntu logo; all that happens is sometimes the screen goes into a Matrix-like loop of flashing computer script in white and green and purple, sometimes getting caught there for minutes, flashing almost too quickly to read. It always boots back into Ubuntu though which, interestingly enough, doesn't require a password to log in, it just sends me right to my desktop.

Comment: Maybe I can boot right from an ISO on the desktop I thought but that seems sketchy so I'd rather do it from a USB if I can. After some research it seems I have UEFI and not BIOS set up. This seems to be an important distinction.